# Почти весь столовый виноград в Крыму – импортный. Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

*Почти весь столовый виноград в Крыму – импортный.*

Answer (score 2):

По правилам здесь возможно авторское тире (именная часть сказуемого выражена прилагательным), и **поставить это тире желательно в связи с распространенностью группы подлежащего**, которую желательно отделить паузой от сказуемого.